# Deployed Laravel sanctum application not working anymore

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

I use sanctum for my vue Axios operations. I deploy to my shared hosting and I get this error in the chrome console:

> GET http://foo.xyz/city 401 (Unauthorized)

bootstrap.js :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}


window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

Axios Get :

```
   getCity() {
            axios.get('/api/city')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.cities= response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

        },
```

Everything is working in my localhost when I deployed this project into my shared hosting nothing worked, so how I can run this in my shared hosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code to the `.env`

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS="foo.xyz"
```

and problem solved.

PS:

> `foo.xyz` is not the actual domain, I gave a different domain for security reasons.